# How to remove those items?

Tags: github

## How to remove those items on the left of github index?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Click on it
- Under the repository name, click Settings.
- Under **Danger Zone**, click **Delete this repository**.
- Type the name of the repository
- Click **I understand the consequences, delete this repository**.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-repository-settings/deleting-a-repository

Comment: But those repository is not created by me, maybe I stared or issued it, Now I want to remove those repositorys.

Comment: maybe this would help: https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-access-to-your-personal-repositories/removing-yourself-from-a-collaborators-repository

Comment: My repositorys not containers it.

Comment: go to Settings -> Repositories